# How to obtain the tilt angle of an android phone?

Tags: android

In my application, I need to calculate the angle at which a user is holding the phone. Is there a way to obtain the tilt angle, perhaps in all three planes?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [`SensorManager.getOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) and [`SensorManager.getRotationMatrix`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. You can refer to sample on Android developers site named AccelerometerPlay.

Answer (score 1):

Orientation is magnetic,  and is dependent on surrounding fields (also generated by electric installations nearby), accelerometer provides gravity vector,  but is pretty noisy. It's your choice what errors do you like more.  I would consider to combine both sensor data